# Oil rush will not go beyond launcher

Tags: 12.04

I bought **Oil Rush** from Software Center.

When I click on the icon from the Unity launcher, it will launch the Oil Rush launcher, but when I click on **run**, it closes the launcher and seems to start, but it doesn't launch anything.

Comment: Your comment in sparse in details.  Please include the bit number of Ubuntu (32- or 64-bit), and some hardware information.  Also, this is an application-specific problem.  Have you considered filing a bug report with the developers?

Comment: I have the 32 bit ubuntu, HP laptop